# I know it uses convolution theorem of inverse Laplace function but wasn't able to apply it .

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

> Find inverse laplace for:
>      $$f(s)=\dfrac  1{(s-2)(s+2)^2}  $$

I know it uses convolution theorem of inverse Laplace function but wasn't able to apply it .

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: No need to use the convolution theorem. Split up the expression into partial fractions, then take the inverse transform of each resulting term. (But if you're supposed to apply the theorem, proceed with that.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use the Convolution Theorem then :
$$f(s)=\dfrac 1 {(s-2)(s+2)^2}$$
$$f(t)= \int_0^t e^{2(t-\tau)}\tau e^{-2 \tau} d\tau $$
$$f(t)= e^{2t}\int_0^t e^{-4\tau}\tau  d\tau $$
$$f(t)=\frac 1 {16}e^{2t}-\frac 1 {16}e^{-2t}-\frac 14 te^{-2t}$$

---

**A simpler way:**

$$f(s)=\dfrac 1 {(s-2)(s+2)^2}$$
Decompose into simple fractions:
$$f(s)=\dfrac A {(s-2)}+\dfrac B {(s+2)}+\dfrac C {(s+2)^2}$$

You should find:
$$(A,B,C)=\left (\frac 1 {16},-\frac 1 {16},-\frac 14 \right)$$
Then apply inverse Laplace Transform on each fraction.
$$f(t)=\frac 1 {16}e^{2t}-\frac 1 {16}e^{-2t}-\frac 14 te^{-2t}$$

Answer (score 0):

The inverse Laplace Transform is given by

$$f(t)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{2^+-i\infty}^{2^+ +i\infty}\frac{1}{(s-2)(s+2)^2}e^{st}\,ds$$

For $t>0$, we close the contour in the left-half plane $s<2^+$.  Note that $F(s)e^{st}$ has a simple pole at $s=2$ and a second-order pole at $s=-2$.

The associated residues of $F(s)e^{st}$ are $\frac{e^{2t}}{16}$ at $s=2$ and  $-\frac14 te^{-2t}-\frac1{16}e^{-2t}$ at $s=-2$.

Hence, we find that for $t>0$

$$f(t)=\frac1{16}e^{2t}-\frac1{16}e^{-2t}-\frac14 te^{-2t}$$

---

For $t<0$, we close the contour in the right-half plane.  Since $F(s)e^{st}$ is analytic in that plane, $f(t)=0$ for $t<0$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.